# Uncaught ReferenceError when trying to load JSONP

Tags: javascript, json, jsonp

I am trying to use this script to load an external JSONP file:

```
var loadJSONP = (function(){
  var unique = 0;
  return function(url, callback, context) {
    // INIT
    var name = "_jsonp_" + unique++;
    if (url.match(/\?/)) url += "&callback="+name;
    else url += "?callback="+name;

    // Create script
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.type = 'text/javascript';
    script.src = url;

    // Setup handler
    window[name] = function(data){
      callback.call((context || window), data);
      document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].removeChild(script);
      script = null;
      delete window[name];
    };

    // Load JSON
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
  };
})();
```

Source: https://gist.github.com/132080/110d1b68d7328d7bfe7e36617f7df85679a08968

Unfortunately I get a **Uncaught ReferenceError: bd is not defined error** when I try to parse the JSON file. The JSON looks like the code below:

```
bd([
    {
        "brand": "brand_1",
        "brand_status": "1"
    },
    {
        "brand": "brand_2",
        "brand_status": "1"
    },
    {
        "brand": "brand_3",
        "brand_status": "1"
    }
]);
```

Has any one got any ideas on how I can get around this error? As it's a third party changing the JSON file format is unfortunately not an option. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: What URL are you requesting? Why do they put `bd` for the name of the function, was that the parameter you passed them? Or don't they support JSONP at all?

Comment: Hi Bergi, thanks for your response. I can't share the URL as it's not public at the moment. But the JSON URL I am requesting is the same format as above. The function I am using to call the URL can be viewed at the link I included. The name of the function the third party use is bd. I presume they support JSONP as in the url string it has &FORMAT=jsonp.

Comment: Well, looks like they don't if you call `…&callback=_jsonp_1` and they send back `bd(…)`. Check their docs if you need to use a different parameter.

Comment: Ok thanks Berg, I will try and get access to their docs.